# Wake lock does not seem to work

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I'm developing an app in which i need the TCP connection to stay alive. I've implemented a kind of ping/pong system to do this. It works perfectly when the screen is on, but when it goes of the phone stops responding to the pings after a while. I've created a Wi-Fi wake lock but i'm still experiencing still the same problem..

This is my code:

```
private static WifiManager wm = getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
private static WifiLock wl = null;

public static void lock(){
    wl = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL , App.TAG);
    if(!wl.isHeld()){
        wl.acquire();
    }
}

public static void unlock(){
    if(wl != null){
        if(wl.isHeld()){
            wl.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you invoke 'acquire()' method on WakeLock object ?

Comment: what is wi-fi wake lock ? Do you mean screen lock ?

Comment: I've updated the question with my code

Answer (score 2):

You have to acquire PowerLock from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) with SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK/PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK flag.

Comment: so it's not possible to keep wi-fi on when screen is turned off entirely?

Comment: No. It's possible. WiFi-Lock saves you from connection lost. You can use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK also. I think the problem is you didn't acquire CPU-Lock, so your code is not performed.